# Cannot Get list from Observable

Tags: angular, angular6

I want to get a list of strings using `localStorage` as pesented by:

```
this.userService.getExpertisesListByIdUser(2).map((listExpertises: Array<any>) =>
      {
          let result:Array<Expertise> = [];
          let libs:Array<String> = [];
          if (listExpertises)
          {
              listExpertises.forEach((expert) =>
              {
                  libs.push(expert.name);
                  result.push(new Expertise(expert.id, expert.name, expert.username));
              });
          }

          localStorage.removeItem("libs");
          localStorage.setItem("libs", JSON.stringify(libs));

      })

      var storedNames = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("libs"));
      console.log(storedNames.length);   // That gives 0 as length : WRONG
```

the method **getExpertisesListByIdUser** is:

```
getExpertisesListByIdUser(id: number): Observable<any>
{
    return this.http.get(`${this.baseUrl}/users/expertises/${id}`);
}
```

As commented I got the length as 0.
I got the correct result if I put `localStorage` outside `map`.
But, I need it inside `map` to get the **synchronization**.

Now, the size is correct whith this code.

```
this.userService.getExpertisesListByIdUser(2).subscribe(listExpertises => {

         let libs:Array<String> = [];
         let exps:Array<Expertise> = [];

         if (listExpertises)
         {
             listExpertises.forEach((expert) =>
             {
               libs.push(expert.name);
               exps.push(new Expertise(expert.id, expert.name, expert.selected));
             });
         }

         localStorage.removeItem("libs");
         localStorage.setItem("libs", JSON.stringify(libs));

         localStorage.removeItem("exps");
         localStorage.setItem("exps", JSON.stringify(exps));

      });

      var storedNames = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("libs"));
      var storedExperties = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("exps"));
      console.log("----------------- Size: " + storedNames.length);
      console.log(storedNames);

      storedNames.forEach((name: string) =>
      {
          console.log("--------------Name from list of strings: " + name);
      });

      storedExperties.forEach((exp: Expertise) =>
      {
          console.log("--------------Name from list of objects: " + exp.name);
      });
```

but on console I got:

[image: screenshot of empty list]

Could you please tell me what I missed ?.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think you missed to `subscribe`

Comment: Hello Sir @splash, it works.

Comment: You can do same using map too but then you will also have to use
 var storedNames = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("libs"));
 console.log(storedNames.length);
inside map

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried using `.subscribe()`?

```
this.userService.getExpertisesListByIdUser(2).subscribe(listExpertises => {
   let result:Array<Expertise> = [];
   let libs:Array<String> = [];
   if (listExpertises)
   {
       listExpertises.forEach((expert) =>
       {
         libs.push(expert.name);
         result.push(new Expertise(expert.id, expert.name, expert.username));
       });
   }

   localStorage.removeItem("libs");
   localStorage.setItem("libs", JSON.stringify(libs));

   var storedNames = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("libs"));
   console.log(storedNames.length);
});
```

`.map()` should only be used if you want to add pipe functions to your observable. Also you don't have to define the response type inside of the subscribe function. If you want to define your response type you do that when using http client

```
getExpertisesListByIdUser(id: number): Observable<yourTypeHere>
{
    return this.http.get<yourTypeHere>(`${this.baseUrl}/users/expertises/${id}`);
}
```

Comment: @Missar Of course you need to be sure that what you receive from the response isn't an empty array/list.

Comment: @Missar You shouldn't edit an answer to ask a question surrounding the answer. You should ask in it's comments. You say that the length of the list from response is 1 but you don't get any desired values from it. In that case you should `console.log()` the list to inspect it first.

Comment: @Missar what I meant was that you should log the whole object and not it's length. Like this: `console.log(listExpertises)` in the top of the subscribe function.

Comment: Sorry Sir @kebbaben about that. I return back the response. the `console.log(listExpertises)` produces an empty list. I attached in my question a screenshot. Could you please take alook. Big thanks Sir.

Comment: @Missar and you log this the first thing you do in the subscribe function? If so then the problem lies in the http response. The array it self is not null but one element in it is. This probably means that the function linked to `${this.baseUrl}/users/expertises/${id}` is the one at fault here. Check that function and make sure that the url is correct on both sides.

Comment: the url `http://localhost:6227/api/auth/users/expertises/2` produces on postman `[
    "Angular"
]`

Comment: @Missar Then are you sure that the url is correct in your code? Are you 100% sure that the ${id} is in fact 2 when you call the function?

Comment: Ok Sir, I found it. I have to add constructor with fields on the entity (Spring Boot). Big thanks Sir

Comment: By the way Sir, have you please another method to maintain the synchronization from `inside subscribe` to `outside subscribe` other then `localStorage`.

Comment: @Missar just save `libs` in a local variable instead of setting it to localStorage if you just want to keep it in the same file.

Comment: But that cannot maintain synchronization from `inside subscribe` to `outside subscribe`.                                                                                                                                  
 `this.userService.getExpertisesListByIdUser(+userId).subscribe(listExpertises =>
{
 if (listExpertises)
    {
        listExpertises.forEach((expert) =>
        {
             this.libs.push(expert);
        });
    }
});

this.libs.forEach((name: string) =>
{
    console.log("--------------Name: " + name);
});`  I got null value so

Comment: @Missar syncing with observables are hard and usually the wrong way to go. Usually you do everything related to the data from an observable **inside** the subscribe function. Read more about [Observables](https://angular.io/guide/observables) and [Observables in Angular](https://angular.io/guide/observables-in-angular)

Comment: @Missar if this has helped you, would you mind marking as answer?

Answer (score 0):

Use `.subscribe`

like this:

```
  this.userService.getExpertisesListByIdUser(2).subscribe((listExpertises: Array<any>) => {
    console.log(listExpertises)
    ... // rest of your code
  })
```

Comment: @Missar You shouldn't edit an answer to ask a question surrounding the answer. Please show console.log(listExpertises)

Comment: Sorry Mrs @AdritaSharma about that. I return back the response. the console.log(listExpertises) produces an empty list. I attached in my question a screenshot. Could you please take alook. Big thanks Mrs.

Comment: It seems you have a problem with backend. Try with postman and check

Comment: Hello Mrs@AdritaSharma, in postman, it was OK. I got                                               
`[
    "Angular"
]`

Comment: Ok Miss, I found it. I have to add constructor with fields on the entity (Spring Boot). Big thanks Miss.
By the way Miss, have you please another method to maintain the synchronization from `inside subscribe` to `outside subscribe` other then `localStorage`.